# How reindexing process is works in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, price, reindex, magento2.4

If i have 1 lakh product in my store and i have re-index in Magento 2.

If i changed a product price so it is required to re-index in magento 2 to see the updated price.

And if it is required to re-index then Magento will re-index all the product from starting or just re-index the updated one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can perform both type of re-indexing

a) Full reindex, which means rebuilding all the indexing-related database tables.

b)Partial reindex, which means rebuilding the database tables only for the things that changed (like changing a single product attribute or price)

Please follow the given link for more detail :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html#indexing-types

Comment: Thanks for the response one more question if i have 1 lakh product in store then update 50 more product then it will reindex 1 lakh 50 product or just 50 product.
will you please help me with this.

Comment: bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute
Will only index your Product EAV Attributes.
Please do upvote the answer if it is useful.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it will only reindex for catalog_product_attribute and all the remain re-index is required so the product is not shown on my froentend.

Comment: Have you used bin/magento indexer:reindex ?

Comment: Yes I have checked on my local with 1 lakh product it will take 2 minutes 16 seconds but when i added just only 36 products with 1 lakh and on re-indexing it will take 3 minutes 12 seconds so i think it will reindex from 0.
Or on updating the product is there a way to reindex only updated one. Have you any idea regarding this.

Comment: I don't know any command that can only update the changed products.
You can use custom script for that.

Comment: Thanks for your response Have you provide any link regarding the same if you have or tell me about procedure where to start like custom script.